# Testrigor gives error saying invalid URL even though url is correct

Tags: testrigor

I am trying to use this url in test suite in testrigor but everytime it gives error,saying invalid url

Error image view here : https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic6347a8b48a5c71375497238

Url is : https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you trying to use this URL?
When I attempt to launch your url with the "open url" command:

open url "https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/register&language=en-gb"

I get to the target URL just fine:

[image: Screenshot of target URL]